# Loading commands in subfolders of the cogs directory

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Currently im trying to clean up my folder structure for my discord bot and have different sub folders in my cogs/commands directory. Each sub folder is a different command category.

However, I'm having difficulty loading these cogs. I'm getting the following error:

```
[nodemon] starting `python main.py`
cogs\commands
1 - cogs\commands\general
2 - cogs\commands\general\help.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Discord Pandemic\main.py", line 372, in <module>
    client.load_extension(f"cogs.{py_file}")
  File "C:\Users\myalt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 676, in load_extension
    raise errors.ExtensionNotFound(name)
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionNotFound: Extension 'cogs.commands\\general\\help' could not be loaded.
```

Even though the file path is correct?

```
    print(py_file)
    if py_file.endswith('.py'):
        py_file = py_file[5:-3]
        client.load_extension(f"{py_file}")
    else:
        for py_file in glob.glob(f"{py_file}/*"):
            print(f"1 - {py_file}")
            for py_file in glob.glob(f"{py_file}/*"):
                print(f"2 - {py_file}")
                if py_file.endswith('.py'):
                    py_file = py_file[5:-3]
                    client.load_extension(f"{py_file}")
                    print(f"Loaded {py_file}")
                    print(f"lol - {py_file}")
```

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: You're loading the extension using backslashes: `cogs.commands\\general\\help`, it should be a dot `.`

Comment: Oh right, I see.

How should I go about replacing ```\\``` with ```.```?

Comment: You can either use `py_file = py_file.replace("\\", ".")` or simply don't add the `\\\`

Comment: Thanks, just tried .replace!

```for py_file in glob.glob("cogs/*"):
    if py_file.endswith('.py'):
        py_file = py_file[5:-3]
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{py_file}")
    else:
        for py_file in glob.glob(f"{py_file}/*"):
            for py_file in glob.glob(f"{py_file}/*"):
                if py_file.endswith('.py'):
                    py_file = py_file[5:-3]
                    print(f"Loaded " + py_file.replace('\\', '.'))
                    client.load_extension("cogs." + py_file.replace('\\', '.'))```
Works good i think :) thank  you

Answer (score 0):

```
    for py_file in glob.glob(f"{py_file}/*"):
        for py_file in glob.glob(f"{py_file}/*"):
            if py_file.endswith('.py'):
                py_file = py_file[5:-3]
                print(f"Loaded " + py_file.replace('\\', '.'))
                client.load_extension("cogs." + py_file.replace('\\', '.'))
```

Had to replace `\\` with `.` as cogs require `.` filepath